# YUY2 vs YUV 422

Tags: yuv, format-conversion

I am having trouble understanding the exact difference between the two. From research, more discuss the two as being different but a few seem to group them under the "4 2 2" sampling scheme.

---

YUV 422 (I and J versions): "has one luma plane Y and 2 chroma planes U, V.
However, in I422, chroma planes (blue and red projections) are sub-sampled only in the horizontal dimension, still by a factor of 2. Thus, there is the same amount of lines in chroma planes as in the luma plane.

For a 2x2 group of pixels, there are 4 Y samples and 2 U and 2 V samples each. The depth is 4*8+2*8+2*8 = 64 bits per 4 pixels, so 16 bits per pixel."

---

YUY2: "Known as YUY2, YUYV, V422 or YUNV.
In YUY2, the chroma samples are sub-sampled by a factor of 2.
In YUY2, the succession for 2 pixels, starts by one luma for the first pixel, then U, then another luma for the second pixel and then V again."

---

I ask this because I am doing image processing tasks in Matlab and have been converting with YUY2 in mind. I thought it was the same as YUV 422 (the indicated original colour space of my images), but now I am wondering if my conversions are not as accurate as can be.

Comment: So what is your question? These 422 formats only have different channel ordering, therefore it is not possible to be "not accurate" in conversion. It either looks good, or mixed up altogether.

Answer (score 0):

`I422` is planar format, that is, a Luma plane, followed by two Chroma planes, where every plane contains only data for a single channel. Basically a version of [YV16](http://fourcc.org/pixel-format/yuv-yv16/) with swapped U and V planes.

[YUY2](http://fourcc.org/pixel-format/yuv-yuy2/) is interleaved: Four subsequent color components form two horizontally neighbored pixels (aka macropixel).