# How to process a raw 10 bit video signal with opencv, to avoid purple distorted image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, rgb, yuv, uvc

I have created a custom UVC camera, which can streaming a 10 bit raw RGB(datasheet said) sensor's image. But i had to pack the 10 bit signal into 16 bit packets, and write the descriptors as a YUY2 media(UVC not support raw format). Now I have video feed(opened it witm amcap,vlc, custom opencv app). The video is noisy and purple. I started to process the data with openCV and read bunch of posts about the problem, but now I am bit confused how to solve the problem. I would love to learn more about the image formats and processing, but now a bit overhelmed the amount of information and need some guidance. Also based on the sensor datasheet it is a BGGR bayer grid, and the similar posts describe the problem as a greenish noisy picture, but i have purple pictures.

### purple image from the camera

[image: purple image from the camera]

**UPDATE:**
I used the mentioned post [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70718890/how-to-retrieve-raw-data-from-yuv2-streaming) for get proper 16 bit one channel image (gray scale), but I am not able to demosaicing the image properly.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
# open video0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_MSMF)
# set width and height
cols, rows = 400, 400,
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, cols)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, rows)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 0)

# Fetch undecoded RAW video streams
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FORMAT, -1)  # Format of the Mat objects. Set value -1 to fetch undecoded RAW video streams (as Mat 8UC1)
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()#read into np array with [1,320000] h*w*2 byte
    #print(frame.shape)
    if not ret:
        break
    # Convert the frame from uint8 elements to big-endian signed int16 format.
    frame = frame.reshape(rows, cols*2) # Reshape to 800*400
    frame = frame.astype(np.uint16) # Convert uint8 elements to uint16 elements
    frame = (frame[:, 0::2] << 8) + frame[:, 1::2]  # Convert from little endian to big endian (apply byte swap), the result is 340x240.
    frame = frame.view(np.int16)

    # Apply some processing for disapply (this part is just "cosmetics"):
    frame_roi = frame[:, 10:-10]  # Crop 320x240 (the left and right parts are not meant to be displayed).
    # frame_roi = cv2.medianBlur(frame_roi, 3)  # Clean the dead pixels (just for better viewing the image).
    frame_roi = frame_roi << 6  # shift the 6 most left bits
    normed = cv2.normalize(frame_roi, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8UC3)  # Convert to uint8 with normalizing (just for viewing the image).
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(normed, cv2.COLOR_BAYER_GR2BGR)
    cv2.imshow('normed', normed)  # Show the normalized video frame
    cv2.imshow('rgb', gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    cv2.imwrite('normed.png', normed)
    cv2.imwrite('colored.png', gray)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

### from this:

[image]

### i got this:

[image]

**SECOND UPDATE:**

To get more relevant informations about the image status I took some pictures with a different target(another devboard with a camera module, both of the should be blue and the PCB shoulb be orangeish), I repeated this with the test pattern of the camera. I took pictures after every step of the script:
**frame.reshaped(row, cols*2) camera target**
[image: frame.reshaped(row, cols*2)]

**frame.reshaped(row, cols*2) test pattern**
[image: frame.reshaped(row, cols*2)tp]

**frame.astype(np.uint16) camera target**
[image]

**frame.astype(np.uint16) test pattern**
[image]

**frame.view(np.int16) camera target**
[image]

**frame.view(np.int16) test pattern**
[image]

**cv2.normalize camera target**
[image]

**cv2.normalize test pattern**
[image]

**cv2.COLOR_BAYER_GR2BGR camera target**
[image]

**cv2.COLOR_BAYER_GR2BGR test pattern**
[image]

On the bottom and top of the camera target pictures there a pink wrap foil for protect the camera(looks green on the picture). The vendor did not provide me the documentation of the sensor, so i do not know how should look like the proper test pattern, but I am sure that one not correct.

Comment: please present how exactly you did that. please don't call pixels "packets".

Comment: Note: what sensor do (in pixel) is not so much relevant on the output. Sensors are often linear, but most video format are "gamma corrected". And note: raw video formats have often colour casts when you do not use camera profile/primaries (every sensor is special, and colour management is done later: raw: you want raw data from sensor without any additional mangling)

Comment: In case you want us to help you processing the image, we must have access to a raw video frame (2 bytes per pixel). You may follow the same procedure as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70718890/how-to-retrieve-raw-data-from-yuv2-streaming). Make the required adjustments to the specific resolution (note: the example is Windows oriented). In case the image exceeds the site size limit, find a way to share one raw video frame. Add to your post, the code used for grabbing.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. With the post you mentioned i was able to shift the bits and got a proper image. But in the code from the post the image is rendered into a 1 channel image, and when i try to recreate the colors i always got fake colors. i am still try to understand what happening and why, so if have any other source where i could learn more about a topic i would be grateful.

Comment: In case you want to address me, start the comment with @rotem. The BGGR raw format is actually read as single color channel. The conversion to 3 color channels is done by [Demosaicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demosaicing) algorithm. I may be able to help you if you share a 16 bit (single channel) raw image. Please edit your post - add the code used for grabbing, and the code used for conversion to 3 color channels.

Comment: @rotem Thank you for you response, i edited my question based on your guides.

Comment: I am getting [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/025Te.png). Can you post the `frame` after this line `frame = frame.reshape(rows, cols*2)` as PNG image? You know you can save the image using `cv2.imwrite('frame.png', frame)` right? Please take a picture of something more meaningful, so we can check the correctness of the colors.

Comment: @rotem I updated the post with a more relevant atrget and test pattern pictures. I tried using different type of the opencv based demoasicing functions, but none of them looked the proper way, or maybe I missed something?

Comment: I think `cv2.COLOR_BAYER_RG2BGR` gives the best result. The frame `frame.reshaped(row, cols*2)` doesn't make sense. The pattern range is [0, 255] (8 bits) instead of [0, 1023] (10 bits), and it also doesn't make sense.

Comment: @rotem As much I understand the code, reshape needed to create 400*800 2 D array from a linear 320000 long array. And because the 8 bit representation the length had to be double to handle the 16 (2*8 bit) data, than casted it inti 16 bit data and a 400*400 2D array. RG2BGR still not enough and I also have to implement this code in C++, so I continue the search for the solution. But thank you for your help.